# Проблема с проверкой данных в POST с помощью php

Tags: post, php

есть код:

```
if(empty($_POST['uname'])){
$error = " Незаполнено имя ";
echo "<div style='color: red;'> $error </div><br><a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Назад</a>";
}else{
     if(empty($_POST['email'])){
     $error = " Незаполнен e-mail";
     echo "<div style='color: red;'> $error </div><br><a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Назад</a>";
     }else{
          if(empty($_POST['post'])) {
          $error = " НЕ заполнено сообщение";
          echo "<div style='color: red;'> $error </div><br><a href='#' onclick='history.go(-1);'>Назад</a>";
          }else{
          include"/inc/mysqlconect.php";
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $post = $_POST['post'];
          $user = $_POST['uname'];
          $result = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO gb (uname,post,email) VALUES ('$user','$post','$email')") or die('ошибка бд');
          echo "Сообщение Добавлено <br> <a href='/index.php?mid=8&pid=81'>Гостевая книга</a>";
          }
      }
}
```

почему он проходит проверку на пустоту при пустом поле post
( поле post  -- textarea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_POST['post']) || $_POST['post'] == '' {
 // ваши действия
}
```

И с чего бы это PHP проверял что бы ввели в поле? В данном случае по нажатии кнопки отправляется форма методом POST, и естественно все $_POST существуют, т.к. форма отправлена, но ни как не проверяет что там внутри каждого поля.

По умолчанию все $_POST будут существовать по отправке формы, т.к. функция isset() проверяет именно а есть ли такая переменная у нас, если есть то  { } иначе  { }. Можно проверить как я написал выше, или более универсальный способ, правда вылезет e_warning, но если вас так устроит по пожалуйста:

```
if(length($_POST['post'] > 0)) {
 // ваши действия
}
```

Comment: к вашему сведению:

     if(!isset($_POST['post']) || $_POST['post'] == '') { // кстати скобку закрывающую забыли.

полностью идентично:

    if (empty($_POST['post'])) {

А по теме вопроса - так возможно что в поле - пробелы, поэтому оно и не пусто. Что бы избежать этого - нужно делать `trim`